# scrollMagic - Adding a class resulting in animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollmagic

I have a script that adds a class (called ".new-class" in this example) to an element. Now I'm looking in to fire an animation when said class is added with help of using scrollMagic.

```
// scrollMagic Scene

    var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller({duration: 40000000});

$(".new-class").each(function(){

    var picOverlay = $(this).find(".overlay");

var animateIn = new TimelineMax();

animateIn
.fromTo(picOverlay, 2, {skewX:3, scale:3}, {skewX:0, xPercent:100, transformOrigin: "0% 100%", ease: Power4.easeOut},"-=1")


// Make a scrollMagic Scene

var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    triggerElement: this,
})

.setTween(animateIn).addTo(controller);

});
```

Nothing happens, even though the ".new-class" is added. How do I go about to listen if the ".new-class" is added and then execute the code above? Any answers is much appreciated.

Comment: `duration: 40000000` I guess it's too much time for an animation. Start with a low number, maybe 1000 and change it to what you want once you fix the issue.

Comment: Nice catch, unfortunately that doesn't change anything. Nothing happens even though I removed the duration completely.